# What is the best way to implement many-to-many relationships using ORMLite?

Tags: android, database, relationship, ormlite

I'm currently playing with ORMlite to make a model with tables and relationships.
One relationship is a many-to-many relationship. What's the best way to implement that?

To be more concrete:

Let's say I've got these two tables

```
Product
   id
   brand

Purchase
   id
```

A purchase can have several products and one products can be in several purchases.
Using ORMLite I could have a `@ForeignCollectionField` in each model but I don't think it would work.
The only valid solution I see is to make a third table Product_Purchase to link Product and Purchase with many-to-one relationships.

What do you folks think?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

@Romain's self answer is correct but here's some more information for posterity.  As he mentions there is an example many-to-many [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) project that demonstrates the best way to do this:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/example-many

The example uses a join table with the id's of both of the objects to store a relationship.  In @Romain's question, the join object would have both the `Product` and the `Purchase` object.  Something like:

```
public class ProductPurchase {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private Product product;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private Purchase purchase;
    ...
}
```

The id fields get extracted from the objects which creates a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE `userpost` (`id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT , `user_id` INTEGER ,
    `post_id` INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
```

You then use inner queries to find the `Product` objects associated with each `Purchase` and vice versa.  See `lookupPostsForUser()` method in the example project for the details.

There has been some thought and design work around doing this automatically but right now ORMLite only handles one-to-many relationships internally.

Comment: Ok many thanks Gray! I just wanted to be sure and you explained it well.

Comment: Thanks too for the answer but Gray, this fact is really poorly documented.. Not good for massive android apps which want to use ORMLite..

Comment: Can you be more specific @eento?  Can you write some better docs?

Comment: `lookupPostsForUser()` is here: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/blob/85ea5b40fb2674a57eb81329597bb1e67c326a9c/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/manytomany/ManyToManyMain.java

Comment: I understand why and how this works. However, this changes the representation of the data. Shouldn't a Purchase have a collection (List<>) of Products and the Products have a collection of Purchases they belong to?

Answer (score 6):

Ok I guess the only way to go is to create a third table Product_Purchase.
It is indicated in a [sample project](http://ormlite.com/docs/example-many).

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a ProductPurchase class and manage it like it was another object that has to go into your Database.

You can (but you don't have to) have a Collection of Products inside Purchases (and vice-versa) but they will have to be manually updated/created when you load the relations between Products and Purchases from the ProductPurchase linker table. Having those collections mean nothing for the ORM (you won't and shouldn't annotate them).

If anyone is looking for and Android App with the Many-to-Many relationship I worked on an example:
https://github.com/arthurrauter/ormlite-android