# Android ORM lite composite primary key (from two fields) or many to many relationship

Tags: android, orm

I'm using orm lite library it is very good in one-to-many relations by this way:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "a")
class A {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Integer id;
    ...
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "b")
class B {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Integer id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = "a_id")
    private A a;
    ...
}
```

now, How can i create many-to-many relation?, i have some ideas but i can not do them, 
idea - i created A, B, and AB classes  as this way

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "a")
class A {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Integer id;
    ...
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "b")
class B {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Integer id;
    ...
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "ab")
class AB {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Integer id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = "a_id")
    private A a;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = "b_id")
    private B b;
}
```

i want to make the primary key of AB class as primary (a, b) and remove id column or make uniuqe (a, b) can i do any one ??

Answer (score 1):

1. I think the only way to achieve many-to-many relation in ORMLite - use third table like you suggested. You can take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9179937/5318705

2. I this time there is no possibility to create composite PK. But, anyway, you can leave dummy ID field as PRIMARY KEY and use uniqueCombo constraint:

```
...
@DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Long dummyId;

@DatabaseField(uniqueCombo = true)
    private Integer idA;

@DatabaseField(uniqueCombo = true)
    private Integer idB;
...
```